# Python coveralls not testing "if name == __main__"

Tags: python, unit-testing, coverage.py

I have a file `test_gather.py`

```
import gather

class TestGather(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_01_gather(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(gather.lookup_terms) > 2, True) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This runs in *coveralls*, but the last line is never reached. (https://coveralls.io/builds/3180464/source?filename=tests%2Ftest_gather.py )

My `travis.yaml` is below:

```
language: python
python:
- "3.4"

before_install:
- "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
- "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"

install: 
- pip install .
- pip install coverage
- pip install nose coverage
- pip install coveralls

script:  
- python setup.py nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package pypiview
- coverage run --source=rawdata setup.py test
- nosetests --with-coverage

after_success:
  coveralls
```

How can I configure this to ensure all `tests/test_*.py` files get run so that the last line is also executed?

Comment: The likely reason that the last line isn't executed is due to it being imported as part of a module, and it's not being directly executed itself.  Is that necessarily a bad thing? Do your nose tests require that statement to explicitly be there if you're running the whole suite?

Comment: Yes I can remove that test if I don't want to run the tests manually from command line, but thought there may be a way of calling coverage to that runs them as if they were running alone (ie coverage run test_gather.py)

Comment: Probably not.  The likelihood is that it's invoking the tests through some other means, which is running their own `__main__` namespace, thus importing your tests as modules.  So it'd make sense why they wouldn't be hit.  I'd encourage you to look up how to run an individual test from the CLI with the tool set you're using as opposed to using the `__name__` piece, as that's not automatically guaranteed to be executed, as shown here.

Comment: Haven't we talked before about how you are running your tests three different ways, and you only need one of them?

Comment: :) Hi Ned! Yes, I did try that - many combinations in fact, playing with the config but found that tests wouldn't run - decided to let them run multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using test discovery to find and run the tests.  You don't need the `if __name__` clause at all.  Just delete it.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks @Makoto - I ended up removing the if clause and now run the tests manually or all at once. Works well